# How to remove duplicate result values in Python Multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, permutation, pickle

Here is what I am trying to accomplish:

1. Generate the permutation from the items.
2. Compare the generated string to a pickle file. The pickle file has a few million lines.
3. The problem is that there are duplicate values when running multiprocessing when cores = 2. If cores > 1, there are duplicate values.

Here is my code:

```
import time
import sys
import random
import os
import pickle
import multiprocessing
from itertools import permutations

#contains a few million lines in pickle format to check against permutations
DATABASE = r'C:/Python38/dataSource/'

#values to permute
items = ['apple', 'ball', 'cat', 'dog', 'elephant', 'fish', 'goat', 'horse', 'jaguar', 'kitten', 'leopard', 'monkey', 'nest']


cores = 3 #if cores = 1, no duplicate values

def main(database):
    count = 0
    for word in permutations(items, 3):
        words = ('%s' % ' '.join(word))
        data = words

        logkey = data
        with open("Logs.txt", "a", encoding="utf-8") as f:
            f.write("%s\n" % logkey)
        count = count + 1
        sys.stdout.write('=> %s\r' % count)
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    database = [set() for _ in range(4)]
    count = len(os.listdir(DATABASE))
    half = count // 2; quarter = half // 2
    for c, p in enumerate(os.listdir(DATABASE)):
        print('\rReading database: ' + str(c + 1) + '/' + str(count), end = ' ')
        with open(DATABASE + p, 'rb') as file:
            if c < half:
                if c < quarter: database[0] = database[0] | pickle.load(file)
                else: database[1] = database[1] | pickle.load(file)
            else:
                if c < half + quarter: database[2] = database[2] | pickle.load(file)
                else: database[3] = database[3] | pickle.load(file)
    print('\nDATABASE FILE =>  ' + DATABASE)
    jobs = []
    for r in range(cores):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target = main, args = (database, ))
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()

Results: How to remove the duplicate values when cores > than 1
cores = 1
result: No duplicate values
apple ball dog
apple ball elephant
apple ball fish
apple ball goat
apple ball horse
apple ball jaguar

cores = 2
result: With duplicate values 1x
apple ball dog <---
apple ball dog
apple ball elephant <---
apple ball elephant
apple ball fish <---
apple ball fish

cores = 3
result: With duplicate values 2x
apple ball fish <---
apple ball fish <---
apple ball fish
apple ball goat <---
apple ball goat <---
apple ball goat
apple ball horse <---
apple ball horse <---
apple ball horse
```

Comment: you need to distribute your work to each core, instead you are having each core run the same _exact_ function and create the same permutations. also you can't really be distributing permutations to cores. you should have one core run the permutation and then run the database check in a distributed fashion.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am still new to this and still trying to learn. Any snippet will be helpful.

Comment: you need to change your `main` function to do the database comparison and nothing else, the permutations need to be taken out of that loop and calculated once by a single process

Comment: how and what I need to change.

Comment: this is not a code writing service, like I mentioned you need to change your `main` function and I have told you what the issue was.